# Launching an android application from a web page

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two applications, AppOne and AppTwo.

AppOne is a simple app which exports an Activity so that it can be launched from a webpage with following Intent-Filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="what should be the host for a local page?"
                android:scheme="what should be the scheme?" />
</intent-filter>
```

AppTwo contains an activity which has a WebView. In WebView, I am loading a local html page, index.html with following href

```
<A href="intent://[what should be this URI]">launch app</A>
```

Specifically, I want to know

1. What should be the host name for a page loaded locally?
2. What should be the scheme as per the scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scheme can be anything you want it to be - so choose a word that means something to your  app such as "apptwo".

If your scheme is unique, then you don't need to specify the host in the data part of the intent filter. If you are simply using the link as a trigger (ie. you always load the same page index.htm), then it doesn't matter what the rest of the URL is.

In AppTwo, you then simply have to arrange to load the relevant file into the webview when the intent fires.

```
  <a href="apptwo://trigger">launch app</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read somewhere it is not a good idea to use your own scheme.